# Datetime Type from powershell to access with blank values

Tags: powershell, ms-access

My issue is simple, I have a csv I am importing, my code works perfect until it finds blank values.

I tried setting the blank values to `$null`, Dbnull and others and I keep getting a data type mismatch in criteria expression

> Error: "Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Data
>   type mismatch in criteria expression."

However when manually importing the csv from access, we can see that those empty values stay empty and blank in the column with date time format.

So the expected result would be that if you import the csv in powershell you would also get those empty values for date time but instead they generate an error and are skipped.

Is there a way to cast a blank value as a datetime ? I need the values as blank for data collection purposes and powershell for the ease of scripting in it and modifying it .

If powershell is not possible.

```
if ($_.date) {
    ([datetime]$_.date).ToString('M/d/yyyy H:mm')
}
else {
    [DBNull]::Value
}
```

Now the expected result, is that once I import, those rows with empty date values will show with those values still empty on the database, yet they get skipped due to the error "

Comment: when you say `import the csv in powershell` what do you mean? you have not provided any code NOR have you provided any sample data to work with.

Comment: `$.date` seems to be a weird construct… Try `echo $.date`

Comment: `[DateTime]` cannot be converted to `$Null`, you will get `Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".` You can however do the `[DBNULL]$_.Date = [DBNULL]::Value` to convert it to a `DBNull` type with a null value.
Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I already have aall the code working to import a CSV to the access database, however when passing blank arguments (in the csv those values are blank) to the database, I get the error above